# How can I get and implement waves publickey

Tags: javascript, firebase, api, wavesplatform

I am getting a error in my JavaScript code, which is requesting a public key from my Waves wallet. Can you guys help me to get that? It's the only thing preventing my code from running. I need the public key.

I have the public key here with me, I just need a way to implement that in my JavaScript code.

This is the error in Firebase after I deploy:

**logs in Firebase:**

> Exception from a finished function: Error: Please provide either seed or senderPublicKey

**in their API shows: https://testnode1.wavesnodes.com/api-docs/index.html
GET
​/addresses​/publicKey​/{publicKey}**

Here is the link : https://pastebin.com/AqswyjVC

```js
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    exports.distributeStakingRewards = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {
        const request = require('request')
        //Fetch list of users who has a positive balance for your asset..
        const assetID = 'xxx'
     
        request('https://testnode1.wavesnodes.com/assets/' + assetID + '/distribution', function(err, res, body) {
            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                const bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body)
                var transfers = []
                for (uid in bodyJSON) {
                    var bal = bodyJSON[uid]
                    //Set minimum balance to get rewarded
                    if (bal >= 1) {
                        var reward = '0.005'
                        var transfer = { recipient: uid, amount: reward }
                        transfers.push(transfer)
                    }
                }
                const waves = require('waves-transactions')
                const nodeUrl = 'https://testnode1.wavesnodes.com/'
                const params = { transfers: transfers,assetId: assetID, attachment: 'Weekly staking rewards payout', timestamp: Date.now() }
                const signedTx = waves.massTransfer(params,
                  {
                    'privateKey': 'xxxx',
                  }
                )
                const id = signedTx.id
                waves.nodeInteraction.broadcast(signedTx, nodeUrl).then(tx => {
                    //If tx returns null or undefined tx.id will be undefined === false
                    if (tx.id === id) {
                        console.log('Successfully distributed staking rewards for ' + new Date().toDateString() + 'was complete')
                    } else {
                        console.log('Unable to distribute staking rewards for ' + new Date().toDateString())
                    }
                })
            } else {
                console.log('unable to fetch asset distribution ' + err)
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood your question, but as long as you have the _public key_ you can pass it as `URL parameter` on the endpoints that require it. For example on the endpoint that you've mentioned `[GET] addresses/publicKey/{publicKey}` you can either make an _HTTP GET request_ replacing the `{publicKey}` for the actual key, or just use the _Swagger interface_ to get the response, filling the input with the public key and pressing _Execute_

Comment: thanks man, can you provide a answer with a code so I could reward you? cheers.

Comment: I've written the answer already @raduken

Answer (score 1):

#### Javascript

You need to pass the *publicKey* whenever the request need it. Acording to the *Swagger* definition, it must be passed as URL parameter like so:

```js
let publicKey = 'your-public-key';

request('https://testnode1.wavesnodes.com/addresses/publicKey/' + publicKey, function(err, res, body) {

});
```

#### SwaggerUI

If you want to test the request through the *Swagger Interface* you can press the button <kbd>Try it out</kbd> under the proper request, fill the required input with the *public key* and then press the button <kbd>Execute</kbd>.

[image]